# Is there a way to get the following result in Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

so there are 2 tables.

Table1

```
   month | orders
    Jan  |  10
    Feb  |  4
    Apr  |  7
```

Table2

```
   month | dispatch
    Jan  | 2
    May  | 3
```

I want to get the following result:-

```
   month | orders | dispatch
    Jan  |   10   |   2
    Feb  |   4    |   0
    Apr  |   7    |   0
    May  |   0    |   3
```

What all ways are there to approach this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use full outer join

```
  select coalesce(t1.month,t2.month),coalesce(t1.orders,0)
 ,coalesce(t2.dispatch,0)
  from table1 t1 full outer join table2 t2 on t1.month=t2.month
```

Answer (score 1):

`Full outer join` for all combinations and `coalesce` for defaults as follows:

```
 CREATE TABLE table1 (month text, orders int); 
 CREATE TABLE table2 (month text, dispatch int);
 INSERT INTO table2 (month, orders) values ('Jan', 10), ('Feb', 4), ('Apr', 7);
 INSERT INTO table2 (month, dispatch) VALUES ('Jan', 2), ('May', 3);

 SELECT month, COALESCE(dispatch, 0), COALESCE(orders, 0)
 FROM table1 FULL JOIN table2 USING (month)
 ORDER BY EXTRACT(month FROM TO_DATE(month, 'Mon'))
```